# localhost:8000 not working. It's just loading infinitely?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on Laravel 5.6 and I downloaded code from the server and set it up successfully in localhost.

If run cmd `php artisan serve` then it works correctly but when I open the browser and type `localhost:8000` or `127.0.0.1:8000` and open my project in the browser, then the browser buffers the page infinitely.

Comment: Can you share what your console saying after running `php artisan serve`

Comment: Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000> @AnkurTiwari

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: What do you mean it's infinite? Is the page blank? Does the loading never stop?

Comment: i cant get it what you want ask? @AnkurTiwari

Comment: yes , it's happening like this @Jerodev

Comment: You are using windows or Linux or Mac?

Comment: is this on a clean install of Laravel?

Comment: i'm using windows @AnkurTiwari

Comment: no it's my friend live project code and in server code working find @CodeBoyCode

Comment: I believe you forgot to modify your `.env` and `database.php` file. Just go and check laravel error log file you will get an idea about it.

Comment: i modify `.env` but i don't have any idea about to change `database.php` @AnkurTiwari

Comment: What about laravel error logs?

Comment: here is my last laravel log `D:\\project-path\\artisan(37): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Give permission to storage folder
2. Generate key using php artisan generate:key
3. Make sure you have .env file in root folder
4. Check for HTACCESS redirection
5. Check database connection ( setup correctly )

Still getting issue then provide more details like screen-shot etc.

Comment: `php artisan key:generate` not generate:key